# "To match it up" meaning

Tags: meaning

I appreciate your candid supports

I have a question about a phrase ( possibly. )

[In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSpDOX5LpM4), after Stephan Smith praised the move of Dwight Haward to Washington Wizards, another reporter contends from 1:30~ "I think it's their meaningless moves because of the situation in the East. am, **just to match it up**...

After googling this phrase, I thought if it could possibly mean the reporter said this phrase in order to give a summary or reason or connection to things he will describe later on?

Thank you for your constant and kind support in advance(m_m).

Comment: "Match" or "mach", which is it?

Comment: I think he is saying "match"(m_m).

Comment: He says "Um, just match it up." I don't follow sports jargon, but he appears to be simply saying "Match the actions here with the actions there."

Comment: What do you mean by "(m_m)"?

Comment: Doesn't that emoji exist in the U.S? I apologize. It means "please pardon me". Sorry.

Comment: Ugh, is this a "jargon"? I thought it would be kind of an ordinary expression...

Comment: Sportscasters have their own jargon -- actually several different sets of jargon.  Some is used when discussing a game, other jargon is used when discussing player "trades" and other personnel movement between teams.

Comment: Oh, kindly make an answer, would you please? I am going off a bit for a while, but if you could I appreciate it.

Comment: Unrelated, but I believe the correct emoji is m(_ _)m for "apologizing/sorry" (lit. bowing down with both hands on the floor). (m_m) looks like smiling eyes to me, just like (^_^).

Comment: Ah, thank you for your feedback. Actually, as you may know, Japanese use "apology" trying to mean "Thank you very much". And that emoji, yes, stands for the apology. ( Sorry for using that. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generically, players on teams are said to be a match or good match or bad match with another team. **Match it up** means look at all the moves being made in the East and see what that means for the Eastern Conference of the NBA; see if they are a good match. The commentator thinks that overall, the moves are not good for the Eastern Conference. There is an imbalance that is being created by this.

***match it up*** refers to examining if the moves (it means the moves taken as a whole)  work well or do not. The reporter goes on to criticize the moves.These [moves [1](https://www.nbcsports.com/boston/boston-celtics/breaking-down-nba-eastern-conference-moves) are not good for the Eastern Conference as the Western Conference will get all the great players while the Eastern Conference is left with players who are not big stars.

Therefore, if you match up each player with each team, you Eastern ones are left weaker. Match it up=go through the list as a whole thing and by implication see what the result it. This is a somewhat unusual use of match here. Usually, match up would refer to individual players; here it refers to taking all of them and seeing what the impact is on the Eastern Conference: it is negative.

The word match here means: to check out the moves overall and see the result. Here is another [article](https://www.nbcsports.com/boston/boston-celtics/breaking-down-nba-eastern-conference-moves) that discusses the imbalance that is coming from these moves.