# Is transcription OK here? If not please bust it

Tags: listening

Thank you for your warm and kind support.

This is the continue of the [previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/453515/to-match-it-up-meaning), and I didn't know even the common word "match up" could be a jargon.

This question is equivalent with the transcription. How hard I tried, I can not grasp what he is talking about. However, since the transcription is not basically off topic here, kindly bust it if it perfectly fits with your criteria.

[The video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSpDOX5LpM4) is here

Will someone help me what he is saying from 2:06~

"um Philadelphia. Philadelphia, is **for me**? **pretty**? MB **unknown** **images**? just a different kind of talent other than John Walls...

Thank you in advance even if this is busted.

Comment: "Philadelphia ... I mean just 'embead' and Simmons is different kinds of talents".  No idea what "embead" is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He's talking about basketball players *[Embiid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Embiid) and [Simmons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Simmons)*.

> Philadelphia... Hmpf, I mean just Embiid and Simmons.